# Equivalent of 'mutate_at' dplyr function in Python pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

and thank you in advanced for the help.

I am looking to create multiple new columns in a pandas dataframe, by dividing a subset of existing columns by another existing column, dynamically named with a suffix. Below is dummy code illustrating the general gist of what i want to do, except for 25+ columns with various transformations.

R code

```
library(dplyr)

player = c('John','Peter','Michael')
min = c(20, 23, 35)
points = c(10,12,14)
rebounds = c(5,7,9)
assists = c(4,6,7)

df = data.frame(player,min,points,rebounds,assists)

df = df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(points:assists),.funs=funs(per_min=./min))
```

Expected output

```
 player min points rebounds assists points_per_min rebounds_per_min assists_per_min
1    John  20     10        5       4      0.5000000        0.2500000       0.2000000
2   Peter  23     12        7       6      0.5217391        0.3043478       0.2608696
3 Michael  35     14        9       7      0.4000000        0.2571429       0.2000000
```

I know that I can reproduce the above in pandas as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'player':['John','Peter','Michael'],
                     'min':[20,23,35],
                     'points':[10,12,14],
                     'rebounds':[5,7,9],
                     'assists':[4,6,7]})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['points_per_minute'] = df['points']/df['min']
df['rebounds_per_minute'] = df['rebounds']/df['min']
df['assists_per_minute'] = df['assists']/df['min']

df.head()



 player  min  points  rebounds  assists  points_per_minute  rebounds_per_minute  assists_per_minute
0     John   20      10         5        4           0.500000             0.250000             0.20000
1    Peter   23      12         7        6           0.521739             0.304348             0.26087
2  Michael   35      14         9        7           0.400000             0.257143             0.20000
```

However, I have to do this for 25+ columns, with different transformations, and explicitly naming every column and operation will become rather cumbersome. Is there any pandas replication of this?

Answer (score 5):

Similar to base R, assign by block of columns with basic arithmetic. Often base R translates better to Numpy/Pandas.

R

```
cols <- c("points", "rebounds", "assists")
df[paste0(cols, "_per_min")] <- df[cols] / df$min
```

Python pandas

```
cols = ["points", "rebounds", "assists"]
df[[col+'_per_min' for col in cols]] = df[cols].div(df['min'], axis='index')
```

Answer (score 2):

**Method1**:

Take the list of columns(*if you dont have a list of columns and want to get all columns after the `min` column , use `cols=df.iloc[:,df.columns.get_loc('min')+1:].columns`*)

```
cols=['points','rebounds','assists']
```

create a copy of the subset of those columns by [`df.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`add_suffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) as `_per_minute`, then [`divide`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) them with the `min` column.

```
m=df.loc[:,cols].add_suffix('_per_minute')
df[m.columns]=m.div(df['min'],axis=0)
print(df)
```

**Method2**: [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
cols=['points','rebounds','assists']
df=pd.concat([df,df.loc[:,cols].add_suffix('_per_minute').div(df['min'],axis=0)],axis=1)
```

**Method3**:

directly assign them with string formatting using same logic:

```
cols=['points','rebounds','assists']
df[[f"{i}_per_minute" for i in cols]]=df.loc[:,cols].div(df['min'],axis=0)
print(df)
```

---

```
    player  min  points  rebounds  assists  points_per_minute  \
0     John   20      10         5        4           0.500000   
1    Peter   23      12         7        6           0.521739   
2  Michael   35      14         9        7           0.400000   

   rebounds_per_minute  assists_per_minute  
0             0.250000             0.20000  
1             0.304348             0.26087  
2             0.257143             0.20000
```

Comment: Thank you ! I went with method 3 and it works great

Answer (score 1):

`mutate_at` is superseded by `mutate` and `across`.

Here is how you can do it in a `dplyr` way in python:

```py
>>> from datar.all import c, f, tibble, mutate, across
>>> 
>>> player = c('John','Peter','Michael')
>>> min = c(20, 23, 35)
>>> points = c(10,12,14)
>>> rebounds = c(5,7,9)
>>> assists = c(4,6,7)
>>> 
>>> df = tibble(player,min,points,rebounds,assists)
>>> 
>>> df = df >> mutate(
... #                                             f.min passed to lambda as y
...     across(f[f.points:f.assists], {'per_min': lambda x, y: x / y}, f.min)
... )
>>> df
    player     min  points  rebounds  assists  points_per_min  rebounds_per_min  assists_per_min
  <object> <int64> <int64>   <int64>  <int64>       <float64>         <float64>        <float64>
0     John      20      10         5        4        0.500000          0.250000          0.20000
1    Peter      23      12         7        6        0.521739          0.304348          0.26087
2  Michael      35      14         9        7        0.400000          0.257143          0.20000
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

With the specific goal of making this feel more like dplyr, I really prefer method-chaining solutions because of their syntactic similarity to piped dplyr code.

This solution uses [pandas.DataFrame.assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [dictionary unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#implementation).

```
updated_data = data.assign(**{f"{col}_per_minute": lambda x: x[col] / x["min"]
                              for col in ["points", "rebounds", "assists"]})
```